# solving trigonometry equation $90$ for $ x$

Tags: trigonometry

*Solve each equation for all  values of $x$:

$3\sin x+3=\cos^2 x$

I've tried changing trig values but I don't think its right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3\sin x + 3 = \cos^2 x \Rightarrow 3\sin x+3 = 1-\sin^2 x \Rightarrow \sin^2x+3\sin x+2 = 0 \Rightarrow (\sin x +2)(\sin x + 1) = 0$. Can you continue?

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $2\sin x + 3 = \cos^2 x$, we have, equivalently,

$$3\sin x + 3 = 1-\sin^2 x \iff \sin^2 x + 3\sin x +2 = 0$$

Now set $y = \sin x$, and solve the resulting quadratic.

$$y^2 + 3y + 2 = (y + 1)(y+2) = 0 \iff y = -1 \text{ or } y = -2$$

$$\iff \sin x = -1, \text{ or } \sin x = -2$$

The latter solution we can throw out, since $-1\leq \sin x \leq 1$.